# Animating multiple text-shadows with Jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, css

I'm trying to create the effect of a Neon sign that changes color. For that I'm using (only for Chrome, FF, Safari and Opera) 4 text-shadows all with the same color but with different blur sizes. The static effect looks awesome but I can't seem to be able to change its color since jquery UI does not support changing text-shadow color and the only jquery plugin I found explicitly says that it only works to animate one text-shadow...

So I'm hoping that all you JS masterminds have already solved this problem one time and thus can help me out!

I've seen this effect working (in an AWESOME way) here: http://metafizzy.co/

Anyone care to explain me howit can be accomplished? I don't need anything that fancy...

Thanks in advance!

John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it can be done with the jQuery function `.animate()` like this:

```
$('span#your-neon').animate({
    step : function(now,fx){
         // generate values based on the now parameter (0 < now < 2000)
         // $(this).css('text-shadow','...multiple text-shadows based on the generated values....')
    },
    duration : 2000
})
```

Comment: I think it can also be done in css3's property `animation` http://filmic.eu/blog/css3-looped-animations/

Comment: I'm mostly sure your jquery answer would work since I' mostly sure I can change the css text-shadow color with no problem through jquery.css. However after studying the metafizzy example I realised it was a css3 animation as user338128 said that was triggered through jquery by changing the class of the body to 'color1', 'color2' etc... and through predefined animations it leads the colors to change. Since I don't need anything that fancy I opted to go the css3 animation loop way. Thank you so much for your answers and your time.